# Systemd prevent ExecStop upon systemctl restart <service>

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

Here is my sample service config, I want to only execute the ExecStop upon systemctl stop and skip that when systemctl restart, how is that possible ?

```
[Unit]
Description=Service Watchdog
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
KillMode=process
ExecStart=/opt/watchdog/bin/monit -I
ExecStop=/opt/bin/monit stop all
ExecStop=/opt/watchdog/bin/monit quit
ExecReload=/opt/bin/monit reload
Restart=always
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You want to execute `monit -I` twice? I do not follow. `restart` restarts the job - stops it, and starts it. If you want to reload, then `systemctl reload` it.

Comment: If I do stop and start, i might use stop all and start all services the problem is that we should not start everthing, only those who are previously running, so I might need to save all services that are running and then restart them all

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/313677) for guidance.

Comment: I do not understand your description. From what you describe, you should split the service into multiple services. I do not understand how one service can stop "all" services, neither what "all services" refer to, and how can they be previously running. There is one service you presented.